Purchased Google's Android phone (versus more affordable Chinese Android phones) due to promise of root, but have not found without desktop how `su`
All other Linux distributions (except Android) allow to use su (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) as soon as you first boot, Windows allows to use superuser as soon as you first boot, what does Android require to use this?
The phone is advertised to allow customization; purchased developer phone just to use su.
Does Android have an exact requirement that you must interface with external hardware (to do a ROM flash) just to use sudo/su? If yes, what is the documentation of this? If not, what other approaches to do this?

Question is; without a desktop, how to use this: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html

Probably duplicate of Why don't Android phones come rooted from stock? and Why don't we get the root key for "our" android?. Further related reading: Why are there not generic phone OS installers? and Bootloader/BIOS, flashing ROMs and related risks. Why are Android devices more brickable than PCs?

I'm cleaning up the comments here as some of them are outdated after the edit, and the others are irrelevant to the question. Please use comments only for the stated purposes.
